# Alarm and Sleep in linux

Tags: c, linux, unix

Is anyone concerned about the combination of `sleep()` and `alarm()`?  I have always heard that it was bad to do because they may both rely on the same timer and conflict with each other.

I think that using `alarm()` is prone to errors and would like to see a different solution or any idea so that I can remove alarm from my code with something much compatible with sleep .

Comment: Have you tried it? What are your observations?

Comment: I am already using these things in my code..and it is working for me..but sometimes it has undefined behaviour..I want to remove the alarm with timer_create or setitimer or any thing..I mean i don't know what will be efficient.

Comment: @HAL In this case, trying it isn't really a great way to make a good decision here since it's system dependent. He might be lucky and his system doesn't conflict. Then trying just gives wrong conclusions.

Comment: For Linux specifically, there isn't much to worry about except for the obvious (signal interrupting sleep, but that's irrespective of using alarm -- other signals will interrupt it anyway). However, as by the standard, sleep _may_ be implemented _using_ alarm. You might possibly have to support something that isn't precisely Linux in the future, even if right now you don't think you will ever. If that ever happens, you'll be angry with yourself for being so short-sighted.

Comment: You could use [select(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/select) for the sleep instead. IIRC it shouldn't interfere with the `alarm` calls.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a `sleep`, the process goes to sleep state for the time mentioned in milliseconds and the `alarm` will return the remaining seconds after `sleep`. An `alarm` terminates the process after mentioned amount of time.

And yes, `sleep` and `alarm` will use the same timer. So it is our responsibility to calculate remaining seconds  when a `sleep()` occurs after an `alarm()`.

For example:
If you use

```
alarm(5);---------------> An alarm is set for 5 seconds.

sleep(3);---------------> Process goes to sleep state for 3 seconds.

alarm(7);---------------> This alarm returns the seconds remaining after sleep is set i.e it returns 2.
```

Then the `alarm` is set for 7 seconds. Totally the process terminates after 12 seconds, when the process time is more than 12 seconds.

If the `sleep` time is more,

Example 2:

```
alarm(5);

sleep(7);
```

Then the process terminates after 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes i can understand..but this thing gonna be much complicated.Do u have any idea so that i can remove alarm from my code with something much compatible with sleep .

Comment: It this behavior garanteed anywhere? The alarm manpage simply says `sleep(3) may be implemented using SIGALRM; mixing calls to alarm()  and sleep(3) is a bad idea.` without describing the (sane) interaction you describe.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible compatibility problems with mixing `sleep` and `alarm`.

The first is that `sleep` will be interrupted by signals, like those from `alarm`. So you always have to check if your `sleep` actually slept for as long as you wanted it to.

But the second potentially bigger problem is that on some systems `sleep` might internally be implemented as something like: `alarm(s); pause();` without properly resetting the previous `alarm` which practically means that `sleep` will destroy any alarm you might have set up.

If your functionality really depends on being able to sleep and get alarms that are independent of each other, look at setting up your own timers with `setitimer` and build your own timing framework around that. When going to sleep, set the itimer to the length of the sleep and `pause()` (checking if you were awakened early by some other signal) and then set back the timer to whatever the alarm was.

Comment: yes i can use setitimer to replace alarm.but i think setitimer,alarm,sleep belongs to same category,will give undefined behaviour sometimes.But setitimer has three option to set timer like TIMER_REAL,TIMER_PROF,TIMER_VIRTUAL.Does anyone more compatible with sleep.

Comment: Well, I mean replace both alarm and sleep with your own thing rolled around setitimer. Not just one of them.

Comment: @Art..Agreed..But i don't want to touch sleep.It will be much hectic to replace all the sleep from my code.For me it will be easy to replace alarm.As per my observation I can use Timer_create(create timer for a particular process).But i found much complexity in it.Do u have any other suggestion.

Comment: "replace all the sleep"? I have two reactions to that. One is that you just make a function that behaves the same and then replace all the function calls to sleep with that function. It's trivial. The second reaction is: why do you have that much sleep in your code? In the past 20 years I can count the number of times I've used sleep on my fingers and those were almost always situations with throw-away code where I was too lazy to do proper synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that using alarm() is prone to errors and would like to see a different solution or any idea so that I can remove alarm from my code with something much compatible with sleep.

`sleep()` is implemented using `SIGALRM`, `nanosleep()` is not, so I would suggest replacing `sleep()` with `nanosleep()`.

Comment: At this stage i can't replace sleep with nanosleep.Do u have any idea to replace alarm.

Comment: @user2814189 You can replace `sleep()` to `nanosleep()` with library interposing. Alternatively, re-implement `alarm()` with `setitimer()`. A better approach is to avoid both of this functions all together because they don't interact well with threads.

Comment: ..Since sleep() and setitimer() both are implemented with SIGALRM so replacing is non beneficial.Do u have any other suggestion apart from setitimer(). Term library interposing is unknown for me.

Comment: @user2814189 Correction: `timer_create()`, not `setitimer()`.

Answer (score 0):

Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) man page.

Recent Linux also provides [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (and `ppoll(2)` and `select(2)` and `pselect(2)`...), [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html), [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html), [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html), [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html), [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) ...